# var used in its own initializer

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang

The following code :

```
    auto getConnection(const std::string &name) {
        constexpr const std::size_t id{findFactoryId(_factories, name)};
        const auto factory = std::get<std::integral_constant<std::size_t, id>{}>(_factories).second;
        for (auto &connection : _connections[id])
            if (connection.first) {
                connection.first = false;
                decltype(factory()) &res = std::experimental::any_cast(connection.second);
                return res;
            }
        _connections[id].emplace_back(std::make_pair<bool, std::experimental::any>(false, factory()));
        decltype(factory()) &res = std::experimental::any_cast(_connections[id].back().second);
        return res;
    }
```

compile with clang++, but with g++ gives this error:

```
In file included from main.cpp:2:0:
src/core/include/connectionpool.h: Dans la fonction membre « auto Core::ConnectionPool<Connectors>::getConnection(const string&) »:
src/core/include/connectionpool.h:28:79: erreur : the value of « id » is not usable in a constant expression
             const auto factory = std::get<std::integral_constant<std::size_t, id>{}>(_factories).second;
                                                                               ^~
src/core/include/connectionpool.h:27:41: note : « id » used in its own initializer
             constexpr const std::size_t id{findFactoryId(_factories, name)};
                                         ^~
src/core/include/connectionpool.h:28:81: erreur : the value of « id » is not usable in a constant expression
             const auto factory = std::get<std::integral_constant<std::size_t, id>{}>(_factories).second;
                                                                                 ^
src/core/include/connectionpool.h:27:41: note : « id » used in its own initializer
             constexpr const std::size_t id{findFactoryId(_factories, name)};
                                         ^~
src/core/include/connectionpool.h:28:81: note : in template argument for type « unsigned int » 
             const auto factory = std::get<std::integral_constant<std::size_t, id>{}>(_factories).second;
                                                                                 ^
```

I'm using those command to compile:

```
(clan)g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -Wextra main.cpp
```

with `g++ v6.3.1` and `clang++ v3.9.1`

The only link that look like to correspond to my issue is a bug report for gcc4.9 (which is solved) : https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59937.

A minimal working example is available [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2f1478ab1a02ed45).

From what I've understood of `gcc` error message, I should not have any error: `id` isn't used to initialise itself.

Should this code yield an error or not ?

If it should raise an error, what could I do to solve the error ?

Thank you for your answers.

The complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>
#include <experimental/any>

template <class F, class... Ts>
constexpr void for_each_in_tuple(const std::tuple<Ts...> &tuple, F f) {
    for_each_in_tuple(tuple, f, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>());
}


template <class F, class... Ts, std::size_t... Is>
constexpr void for_each_in_tuple(const std::tuple<Ts...> &tuple, F f, std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    using expander = int[];
    (void) expander{0, ((void)f(Is, std::get<Is>(tuple)), 0)...};
}

template <typename... Connectors>
class ConnectionPool {
    public:
        auto getConnection(const std::string &name) {
            constexpr const std::size_t id{findFactoryId(_factories, name)};
            const auto factory = std::get<std::integral_constant<std::size_t, id>{}>(_factories).second;
            return factory();
        }

    private:
        struct foo {
            constexpr foo(std::size_t &i, const std::string &name) : i(i), name(name) {}
            template <class T>
            constexpr void operator()(const std::size_t is, const T pair) {
                i = name == pair.first ? is : i;
            }
            std::size_t &i;
            const std::string &name;
        };

        template <class Tuple>
        static constexpr std::size_t findFactoryId(Tuple &tup, const std::string &name) {
            std::size_t i = 0;
            for_each_in_tuple(tup, foo(i, name));
            return i;
        }

        std::tuple<std::pair<std::string, std::function<Connectors()>>...> _factories;
};


int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**

Change link to minimal working example: a function was missing.

**EDIT 2**

Add minimal working example in the post

Comment: The error is pretty clear, `findFactoryId()` does not provide a `constexpr` from gcc's point of view, you should better post its body here.

Comment: Can you simplify the code example into a [MCVE]?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is on this line:

```
constexpr const std::size_t id{findFactoryId(_factories, name)};
```

The initializer of a `constexpr` variable must be a constant expression. In a constant expression you can not use the `this` pointer. You are implicitly using the `this` pointer by referring to `_factories`, which is a data member.

> N4296 [expr.const] ¶2
>
> A *conditional-expression* `e` is a *core constant expression* unless the evaluation of `e`... would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> - `this`, except in a `constexpr` function or a `constexpr` constructor that is being evaluated as part of `e`;
> - ...

Surprisingly, both compilers are happy if we simply use an explicit `this`:

```
constexpr const std::size_t id{findFactoryId(this->_factories, name)};
```

But I do not believe that is conformant. Here is a portable workaround:

```
const auto _this = this;
constexpr const std::size_t id{findFactoryId(_this->_factories, name)};
```

Comment: So why clang compile without error when it should not ? Is this a bug in clang ?

Comment: Yes. As far as I can tell, it was allowed in C++11, but that was a [defect](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1369). It was intended to allow `this` in a `constexpr` function, not a constant expression. C++14 [relaxed `constexpr`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3652.html) tightened up the rules on `this` but it seems implementations have varied in their uptake.

Comment: @Oktalist I would like to understand that workaround `const auto _this = this;`. Can I also apply it in [this simpler example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46688093)?

Comment: @Julius No, it's not related.