# `constexpr` variable "used in its own initializer": Clang vs. GCC

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++17, constexpr

This question seems related to [an existing one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43745569), but I do not understand the "portable workaround" provided in [the answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43745569/#43748514) (involving `const auto this_ = this;`) and moreover I think the following example is easier to follow.

I am playing with the following snippet of C++17 code ([live demo](https://godbolt.org/g/QZca1m)):

```
#include <iostream>

struct Test {
  const char* name_{nullptr};
  const Test* src_{nullptr};

  constexpr Test(const char* name) noexcept
    : name_{name}
  {}

  constexpr Test(const Test& src) noexcept
    : src_{&src}
  {
    name_ = src_->name_;
    src_ = nullptr;
  }
};

template<char c>
void print_constexpr_char() {
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  constexpr const char* in = "x";
  constexpr auto foo = Test{in};
  constexpr auto bar = Test{foo};
  std::cout << bar.name_ << std::endl;

  print_constexpr_char<bar.name_[0]>();

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation fails with GCC 7.2 while Clang 5.0.0 does not see any problem. The GCC error essentially reads

> error: the value of 'bar' is not usable in a constant expression
>
> note: 'bar' used in its own initializer

I am even more confused after realizing that removing the final `print_constexpr_char` makes the code compile although it still contains the line `constexpr auto bar = Test{foo};` which GCC used to complain about ("used in its own initializer").

1. Which compiler is correct here?
2. How to understand the GCC note (if not a bug) that "using in its own initializer" is harmful iff the result is subsequently used in a constant expression?
3. Is there a valid way/workaround to use pointers in a `constexpr` constructor as an intermediate stage before transforming the object under construction into the final state which can be stored in a `constexpr` variable?

Comment: MSVC also compiles this without error.

Comment: Could this be related?
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59937

Comment: This [compiles in gcc 5.1](https://godbolt.org/g/ccFUix).

Comment: Minimized example: https://godbolt.org/g/m3qcmP

Comment: I am not sure if the bug is related: It is marked as "fixed" and the examples did not include addresses (other than char literals and references).

Answer (score 10):

GCC is correct to reject the code (however the error message could use some work). You cannot use the address of a variable in a constant expression unless that variable has static storage duration.

`foo` is not static. If you move it outside of `main`, things will work. [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RswS0DYmaaJBxR0L)

The line marked below is the problem:

```
constexpr Test(const Test& src) noexcept
: src_{&src} <--- That
```

Standard reference: (**Emphasis** mine)

[expr.const]

> A *constant expression* is either a glvalue core constant expression that refers to an entity that is a permitted
>   result of a constant expression (as defined below), or a prvalue core constant expression whose value satisfies
>   the following constraints:
>   
>   
>   (5.2) — if the value is of pointer type, **it contains the address of an object with static storage duration**, the
>   address past the end of such an object (8.7), the address of a function, or a null pointer value,

Comment: I know this rule, but I thought it does not apply in cases like this one. I always assumed that the rule exists to forbid things like `constexpr auto address = &src;`, but using the address in an intermediate stage (not constexpr) I considered to be fine. There are many examples where the compiler did not complain when I use the address in an intermediate stage and then compute the result based on that address. If that result is "address-free", compilers were always happy. Do you mind [an external source](https://godbolt.org/g/5dm5b8) for an example?

Comment: [Here](https://godbolt.org/g/3su3Ux) is an example more similar to the original question where both GCC and clang are fine with taking the address in main: `constexpr auto foo = Test(5); constexpr auto foobar = Test(&foo);`. I thought it works iff the address does not end up in foobar (although it may be used). Is that indeed valid or are both compilers wrong here?

Comment: @Julius: I'm inclined to say they're both wrong. BTW in your second example you use GCC 5.4 instead of GCC 7.2, which rejects it.

Comment: interesting that you say both compilers might be wrong if they accept the use of addresses for computing `constexpr` values. You are right that my second example used GCC 5.4. GCC 7.2 fails there (as I realized after posting the comment). However, [there are simple examples](https://godbolt.org/g/Dku1gf) where also GCC 7.2 allows `constexpr auto foo = Test(5); constexpr auto bar = Test(&foo);`.

Comment: @Julius: I see what you mean. I can come up with other examples that GCC seems to allow, too. I'm inclined to say they're still non-conformant as per the rule I mentioned. There appears to be some conflict between that rule and the one defining a core constant expression that allows a reference type if it "has a preceding initialization and either [...] is is initialized with a constant expression". The rule I cited should take precedence, though.

Comment: I am not an expert here, but I understand the standard such that _inside_ a constexpr function (or constructor) one is _not_ restricted to the use of _constant expressions_. One example in [n4687](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4687.pdf), § 8.20 [expr.const] says before paragraph 3: `constexpr int f2(int k) { int x = k; /* OK: not required to be a constant expression because x is not
constexpr */ return x; }` (slightly modified by me to fit comment). Since your answer refers to what is allowed to be a _constant expression_, I "hope" those restrictions might not apply